# Undefined identifier

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and made a script, a very basic player attacking monster type thing. But i get undefined identifier issues =/

I don't quite understand why, I come from a PHP background so its probably me not totally adapted to C++ strict ways but I'm hoping some one could explain.

The errors:

```
main.cpp(30): error C2065: 'miss' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(31): error C2065: 'hit' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(43): error C2065: 'pmiss' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(46): error C2065: 'phit' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(47): error C2065: 'phit' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(49): error C2065: 'mmiss' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(52): error C2065: 'mhit' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(53): error C2065: 'mhit' : undeclared identifier
```

My script:

```
#include <iostream>


int player_health = 10;
int monster_health = 10;

void main(){

    do{
        std::cout << "#####################################" << std::endl;
        std::cout<< "Pick you're weapon and hit enter!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press k for knife or b for Bat!" << std::endl;
        std::cout <<""<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "Player Health: "<< player_health << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Monster Health: "<< monster_health << std::endl;
        std::cout << "###################################"<< std::endl;
        std::cout<<""<<std::endl;

        char user_weapon;
        std::cin >> user_weapon;

        if(user_weapon == 'k' || user_weapon == 'b'){
            if(user_weapon == 'k'){
                int miss = 5;
                int hit = 5;
            } else if(user_weapon == 'b'){
                int miss = 2;
                int hit =3;
            }
                if((rand() % miss) < 3){
                    int phit = (rand()% hit);
                } else {
                    bool pmiss = true;
                }

            //monster
            if((rand() % 5) < 3){
            int mhit = (rand()%3);
            } else {
                bool mmiss = true;
            }

            if(pmiss){
                std::cout << "Player missed monster!"<<std::endl;
            }else{
                monster_health = monster_health - phit;
                std::cout << "Player hit monster for " << phit << "!" << std::endl;
            }
            if(mmiss){
            std::cout << "Monster missed player!"<<std::endl;
            } else{
                player_health = player_health - mhit;
            std::cout << "Monster hit for " << mhit << "!" <<std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid input , try either k or b" << std::endl;
        }


    }while(player_health >0 || monster_health > 0);
        std::cout << "###################################"<< std::endl;
        std::cout<<""<<std::endl;
    if(player_health < 0 && monster_health < 0){
        std::cout << "It's a draw!" << std::endl;
    } else if (player_health > monster_health){
        std::cout<<"Player Wins!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Monster Wins!" << std::endl;
    }
        std::cout << "###################################"<< std::endl;
        std::cout<<""<<std::endl;
}
```

If you run the script you should get the same errors as I did.

Comment: Whenever you get an error, please copy and paste the exact and entire error in your question. We are unlikely to help without it.

Comment: Add `using namespace std;` after your includes. After that, you won't need to type `std::` any more.

Comment: IMO, it's better to develop a habit of specifying `std::` when you need it than to end up with issues because of `using namespace std;`

Comment: @RetiredNinja: It depends. I mix both approaches together in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(user_weapon == 'k'){
                int miss = 5;
                int hit = 5;
            } else if(user_weapon == 'b'){
                int miss = 2;
                int hit =3;
            }
                if((rand() % miss) < 3){
```

You are defining `miss` in the `if`'s scope, and then using it out of the scope, so in: `if((rand() % miss) < 3){`, you get that `miss` is undefined - because it is defined only in the scope where you declared it.

Note that in c++, you cannot do it, there is static scoping in c++.

You should define `miss` before the `if` scope, and only assign a value to it there.

The same also applies for other variables, such as `hit` and `pmiss`, of course.

Comment: If i set them all to 0 at the top, my .exe crashes =/ but it does fix my initial problem. But brought on a new one.

Comment: @Dave: This is a new problem with new symptoms. Note that: (1) Your previous problem was compile-time, while this new one is run-time. You should try to debug your program with a debugger and check why it fails, and if you cannot find it - you should post a new question, with the new code and new symptoms - I'm sure you will get a response quickly

Comment: Thanks i shall do ! I will accept you're answer once the timer lets me do so!